# Use jQuery's .wrap on all children of a given tag

Tags: jquery

Working jQuery, what I'd like to perform is something similar to the following:

```
$('sometag').children().wrap('<div></div>');
```

With the resulting DOM manipulation wrapping all children in one div, not each child individually.

Starting example HTML:

```
<div>
   <h3>Heading</h3>
   <p>Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

What this line of code does:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <h3>Heading</h3>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I want:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <h3>Heading</h3>
        <p>Paragraph</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

What is the proper syntax to achieve the end result I'm looking for?

Comment: Hey @T.Stone what does your HTML look like before you run the code?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
$('sometag').children().wrapAll("<div></div>");
```

Comment: This would not produce the output he wants. It would simply wrap the `p` tags and leave the `h3` element outside the `div`

Comment: 'sometag' wouldn't work either with his sample code. I was giving a hypothetical use of wrap all. I figured the application was quite obvious.

Comment: This only works when `'sometag'` matches a single element. If not, It will move all children elements (i.e. all elements inside all `<sometag>` s) into the new `<div>`. `wrapInner` was written specifically to handle the OPs use-case, and works when matching multiple [parent] elements.

Comment: In THIS instance, what is the difference from $('sometag').wrap('<div></div>');  and $('sometag').children().wrapAll('<div></div>'); ??

Answer (score 4):

```
$('tag').wrapInner('<div>');
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('sometag').html('<div>' + $('sometag').html() + '</div>');
```

Comment: I like how simple this is, even though `wrapInner` or `wrapAll` is probably the right way to do it. Good job.