# How to wrap the children/child of element with one tag using cheerio?

Tags: javascript, html, cheerio

I have `p` tags inside `div` element.

I want to wrap the `div` children/child with `div` tag using `cheerio` library.

I try to use `wrap`: `$('.parent').children().wrap('<div></div>');` But it wraps every element in my `div`.

Is it possible to wrap all the children with one tag `div` like this:

```
<div class="parent">
 <div>
    <p>Child 1</p>
    <p>Child 2</p>
    <p>Child 3</p>
 </div>
 </div>
```

The code I try to do:

```js
import cheerio from 'cheerio';

const html = `
  <div class="parent">
    <p>Child 1</p>
    <p>Child 2</p>
    <p>Child 3</p>
  </div>
`;

const $ = cheerio.load(html);

$('.parent').children().wrap('<div></div>');

console.log($.html());
// Output:
//   <div class="parent">
//     <div><p>Child 1</p></div>
//     <div><p>Child 2</p></div>
//     <div><p>Child 3</p></div>
//   </div>
```

Comment: No. Because I don't use jquery here, I use cheerio. and cheerio doesn't have wrapAll method.

Comment: [Cheerio has a `.wrapAll` method](https://cheerio.js.org/classes/Cheerio.html#wrapAll), the dupe suggestion seems good: [Use jQuery's .wrap on all children of a given tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760602/use-jquerys-wrap-on-all-children-of-a-given-tag)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use method `wrapInner` like that:

```
$('.parent').wrapInner("<div></div>");
```